# Can I prevent Active Directory from accepting common passwords?

Tags: passwords, windows, password-policy, active-directory

Active Directory's complexity requirements are rudimentary and I suspect this specific part of Windows security hasn't been improved in a decade or more.

Is there a built-in or 3rd party tool available to setup another check before accepting a new user password?

The problem with relying on complexity requirements is that it's simple to meet the requirement but still have a weak password because of password lists.

"Sorry, that password cannot be used. It is one of the Top 100,000 most common passwords."

Comment: I'm confused: do you want to increase complexity or ban a list of passwords?

Comment: What about the complexity requires needs improving?

Comment: Research shows that if you make the complexity rules too complex, then users resort to easier to guess passwords (ones that make it on to lists). The more you limit the creativity of coming up with a password, the more people resort to rote methods.

Comment: @schroeder (1) I had said "another check" meaning keep the complexity requirements I have now while adding the banning of common passwords. (2) One way the complexity requirements could be improved is to relax them as the password gets longer. When password becomes sufficiently long enough (whatever that is) don't require three of four types of characters, just require two. (3) Our rules are 8 chars minimum with complexity turned on. Fairly lax.

Answer (score 2):

There are well-baked drop-in replacements for passfilt.dll that provide more granularity ([and doing so is supported by Microsoft](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms721766(v=vs.85).aspx)). I'm not affiliated, but products like [nFront](http://nfrontsecurity.com/products/nfront-password-filter/) and [Anixis PPE](http://anixis.com/products/ppe/) give you a lot of options, including blacklisting common passwords.

You can also code your own replacement, but that's probably harder than using an existing package.

Comment: I could code my own replacement like I could build my own jet engine. I'll look into those recommendations. They look very interesting.